# BigQuery Table Not Found using the browser tool

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the Browser Tool to create a simple dataset with just 1 table with the following schema:

```
data:integer,count:integer
```

I am uploading the data using a comma separated `csv` file.

When I proceed to create the table I can see the new dataset and table in the left side column and next to *Job History* I see `1 running`.

Nothing happens for a long time, even with a small csv file. When I click on the newly created table I get the error `Table Not Found`

When I refresh the page everything is gone, the dataset and the table.

This looks like some kind of bug, but as I am new with BigQuery I want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong.

If this is a bug, how can I skip it in order to be able to actually create a dataset with a table?

Any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the job history (in the top left corner), you should be able to see the load job that you ran. If it failed, it will show an error.

My assumption is that you ended up running this yesterday when our load jobs were temporarily backed up.  When you run a load job, the UI shows a table placeholder, but the table won't actually exist until the load completes. That is why when you clicked on the table it showed as 'not found' since it hadn't really been created yet. That is also why it didn't show up when you reloaded.

We're in the process of increasing capacity by an order of magnitude, so that should be less likely to happen again.

If you do have jobs that failed that you think should have succeeded, please send the job ID and we can investigate.

Comment: You are right, today when I logged in all my yesterday "attempts" were there